# FB login flow results in blank page inside the Google App on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook

I have an issue with FB login flow in Google App on iOS.

When I redirect to the FB auth. page 
(`window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...", '_self', '');`) the only thing I get, is a blank screen...

It works fine on Chrome, but not inside the Google App.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Update: Opened a bug-report in Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1167434796625687). Response: "This is an issue with the Google App for iOS, not Facebook.". Created a bug-report in the Google App now. Response awaiting.

Comment: According to Facebook, this is an issue with the Google App for iOS. So we opened a bug-report there.

Comment: No response from the Google App so far...

Answer (score 0):

```
var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }

    };



if ( isMobile.Android() ) {
        document.location.href = https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...", '_self', '';
    }
else if(isMobile.Windows())
{
        document.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...", '_self', ''";
}
```

Comment: Hi @rei, Thanks for the reply. I don't seem to understand your answer tough. Could you elaborate further? My issue with the redirect is inside the Google App on iOS.

Comment: You can use the redirection method as follow for this case (by detecting the user agent being chrome ios)
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
See more info here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/
code above,you insert
//fix iOS Chrome
<pre><code>

if(isMobile.iOS())
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='+appID+'&redirect_uri='+ document.location.href +'&scope=email,public_profile', '', null);
else
    FB.login(null, {scope: 'email,public_profile'});<code></pre>

Comment: ah, yes, I'm already doing exactly that. The problem is, that this redirect results in a blank page in the Google App on iOS (not in Chrome). I've filed a bug report at Facebook, but they seem to think it's an issue inside the Google App itself (see my comment under the original post).